# What is an example of Interpolation search being slower than Binary search?

Tags: algorithm, search

I understand that interpolation search not only requires a sorted list but also uniformly distributed. I am looking for an understandable situation where Interpolation search is slower than binary search.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume uniform distribution of the values so we'll use simple linear interpolation. 
So if the values are:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10000000
And we search for number 9,  searching using linear interpolation will go through all (excluding the first and last) the indices before finding the correct one. 
In such cases interpolation search will be O(n).